# USB-to-parallel print on win7 using matrix printer causes empty lines

Tags: windows-7, usb, printing

I am using an USB-to-parallel port adapter on Windows 7. It was recognized by the system, and everything work fine.

BUT: When I print something on an Epson LQ-1050+ printer, empty lines appear between the printed lines. (As if auto line feed were switched on, or something similar)

On a laser printer for example, printing just works fine. (And no other problems with Epson either, just those additional empty lines.)

Any idea?

Thank you very much,

Comment: *"As if auto line feed were switched on"* - So did you verify that auto line-feed DIP switch is turned off?  Maybe the printer driver (advanced printer options) also has an auto line freed option?

Comment: Does the Windows test page print correctly?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be a solution for you, but if you're on a desktop you may want to consider a PCI adaptor for Parallel so that you don't have a media change issue.